# Passing different variables

Tags: linux

I have a shell script that has a variable set in my find command. I need to be able to run the shell script changing the variable string each time. So, filemask will change each time, but all results for each variable should output to the file.

Example:

```
filemask="key_*"
file=/home/file
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "$filemask" > $file
```

The next time I need to change `filemask="say_*"` when I run the shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Your script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
filemask=${1:-"key_*"}
file=/home/file
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "$filemask" >> "$file"
```

---

- filemask variable is set from the command line as the first parameter to your script. In case it is not provided or provided but empty, then the script will make it key_*.
- The results of the `find` command are appended into the file whose name is stored in the $file variable. OTW, everytime you were to run your script, the previous run's contents would be overwritten.